# Mongodb delete documents without associated documents

Tags: mongodb

Yeah the title may sound silly but I have two collections: Visitors and Chats. Chat has a visitor while visitor has many chats. Periodically I delete visitors that have a `last_activity` field lower that x days but I wouldn't wanna delete a visitor who has chat(s) so I need a way to `delete from visitors where last_activity < days_unix_milliseconds and _id not in(select visitor_id from chats)`

I have a working code for the first part (last activity), need help with the 2nd:

```
Visitors.remove({
    last_update: {
        $lt: (new Date()).getTime() - 3600000 * 24 * 7
    }
}, function(error){

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice would be to change your schema so that you *can* do this with just one query. In this case, I would probably just keep a field with each `visitor` that tells you how many chats it has. You can simple increase this each time a user starts a chat with:

```
db.visitors.update( { visitor_id: XXX }, { $inc: { 'chat_count': 1 }  } );
```

And when it ends:

```
db.visitors.update( { visitor_id: XXX }, { $inc: { 'chat_count': -1 }  } );
```

And then removing all visitors that don't have a chat is as simple as:

```
db.visitors.remove( { last_activity: { $lt: XXX }, chat_count: { $lt: 1 } } );
```

Answer (score 2):

So each chat has a field `visitor_id` and you want to delete only visitors whose `_id` does not appear as a `visitor_id` in a chat? You would have to loop over all visitors, check `last_activity` for each, and if it is a candidate for deletion, do a `find()` on chats with that visitor's `_id`. If it turns up no documents, you can delete that visitor.

When you iterate over all visitors, you do that with a MongoDB cursor (the result of a `find()`).  The cursor is implemented in such a way that you can safely delete documents from the underlying collection while iterating over it.

The trick is that you don't attempt to express everything in a single `remove()` call.  You iterate, check, and delete as part of the iteration. You want to make sure that the `find()` inside the loop is very fast, by adding an index on `visitor_id` to the chats collection.

Comment: All of this is true because there are no JOIN in MongoDB. You cannot select where. You can select, select, and loop in your code.

Comment: His suggested SQL version did not use any joins either.

Comment: `Not in select` is a join. It might not be valid SQL but it is the concept of a query where the server needs to read two tables to produce the result. Using the `JOIN` keyword or not is irrelevant. Mongo queries are on a single collection (or table, if you will). You cannot, by design, ask mongo to link two collections.